# Python Processes not joining

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm unable to paste my code snippet, so I'll explain the scenario
1. I have a list of around 50000 stocks that need some valuation
2. These stocks are in a MultiProcess.Queue
3. I create multiple processes, each process will take a batch of 50 from the queue and do something.
4. in the main thread, I have a check which looks like this

```
 anymore_to_process = True

 while anymore_to_process:
     if (stock_queue.qsize() == 0):
         anymore_to_process = False

for jobs in stock_jobs:
    jobs.join()
```

5. however, this doesn't seem to work when i process 50000 records. If I process 500 stocks, this works fine.

what am I doing wrong? Why are the processes not joining when I process a lot of stocks.

I know this is difficult to answer without looking at my code.....but if you can give me some pointers, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you loading all the stocks into the `Queue` prior to launching the child processes?

Comment: Am I understanding that you're creating `50000 / 50` (aka *1000*) processes?  If so, that's not going to end well.

Comment: No...i create only 10 processes.....they take 50 at a time.

Comment: @dano- yes, I'm loading them prior to kicking off the processes

Comment: @user2097496 Do the child processes write anything to a `Queue`, or are they strictly consumers of `stock_queue`?

Comment: "I'm unable to paste my code snippet" means "I don't have a question for StackOverflow". If your worry is that your code is, or relies on, proprietary commercial code… well, nobody cares about your _actual_ code, what we want is a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. If some weird regulations prevent you from event posting such an example from work, you probably shouldn't be posting here at all.

Comment: @dano = no they dont write anything to a queue. However, they return an object which gets added to a dictionary in the main process.

Comment: @abarnert = should have been clearer. the difficulty is extracting the important pieces of the code thats relevant to this discussion. I will try to get the essential parts of the code and add it to this thread.

Comment: Do not use qsize() for checking if queue is empty, use empty() instead. qsize returns approximate number of elements so it is not as reliable as empty()

Comment: @dano is there a difference if the child process writes to **another** `Queue`?

Answer (score 8):

Problem resolved - took a cue from @dano's question.
I was indeed writing to another queue, which was blocking the processes. I took it out and problem resolved.

Comment: This happens because the `Queue` uses a buffer internally when a lot of data is being pushed into it. The process writing to the `Queue` can't exit until that buffer gets flushed, which won't happen until you start pulling things out of the `Queue`. So, because you're trying to `join` all the processes before you pull anything out of the `Queue` objects they're writing to, they can't exit, so the `join` hangs. You could fix the issue by draining the `Queue` prior to calling `join` on the processes.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I am using a queue so child processes can report results back to the main process, but this queue is not emptied until all processes return, which they won't because of what you said. So I use a queue's `join` method (another queue which is consumed by the child processes) instead of the processes `join` method - but isn't there any other way to flush the buffer?

Comment: @dano What does *draining the `Queue`* mean?

Comment: @Ma0 draining the queue means dequeuing all the items in it.