# multiprocess.Queue.get() needs very long time in python

Tags: python, queue, subprocess, threadpool

I need to fetch really big data chunks by iterating over the data. In total I need a few million iterations. So I'd thought subpressing would speed up my process and it almost did. I use `subprocess.Queue` to invoke different Threads, which actually works fine, but when I call *subprocess.Queue.get()`the programm takes forever to get the results. Maybe I did something wrong. Here is my minimal example:

```
def get_losses(self, tags=None):
    return_dict = {}
    output_list = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process_list = []

    # Create quese definition
    for experiment, path in self.tf_board_dicts.items():
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._load_vec_from_tfboard, args=(path, tags, experiment))
        process_list.append(t)
    print("Starting subprocesse with a total of {} workers. \n These are  {}".format(len(process_list),
                                                                                         process_list))
    # Run processes
    for p in process_list:
        p.start()

    # Exit the finished threads
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()
    print("All subprocesses are termianted")

    # Get results
    results = [output_list.get() for p in process_list]
    print("All losses are gathered: {}".format([tup[0] for tup in results]))

    # Create dict
    for experiment_losses in results:
         return_dict[experiment_losses[0]] = experiment_losses[1]

    return return_dict
```

Comment: For debugging try this: results = [output_list.get(timeout=0.1) for p in process_list]

Comment: Thanks, I did and in fact that showed me that the return list was not filled properly. Unfortunately I found the reason, why I does not work. The bottleneck is the loading process and somehow it does not multiprocess this step. But I think this is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer for infinite time issue with queue here : [Python Processes not joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025486/python-processes-not-joining)

> This happens because the `Queue` uses a buffer internally when a lot of data is being pushed into it. The process writing to the `Queue` can't exit until that buffer gets flushed, which won't happen until you start pulling things out of the `Queue`. So, because you're trying to join all the processes before you pull anything out of the `Queue` objects they're writing to, they can't exit, so the `join` hangs. You could fix the issue by draining the `Queue` prior to calling `join` on the processes. – dano Sep 25 '14 at 16:16